# Misunderstanding of an exercise on random variables?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I am trying to to the forward implication of the following question:

[image]

That is:
$ d_{TV}(x, y) = 0 \implies P(X = Y) =1 $

It my be an issue with my understanding of the notation, I believe that $ P(X = Y) = P(\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) = Y(\omega)\})$ where $ (\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P) $ is our measure (probability) space.

We have $ d_{TV}(x, y) = 0 \implies P(X = k) = P(Y = k) \quad \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$

but I can't see how to continue, in fact I thought of a "counter example" to the result.

Let $\Omega$ be the sample space of tossing a fair coin once, let $ X $ map heads to $0$, tails to $1$ and let $Y$ map heads to $1$ and tails to $0$. Then it seems that the result does not hold.

Where is my misunderstanding? I assume it is something trivial since the authors say as much in the solutions (i.e. their solution is 'it's trivial').

Thanks.

Comment: Could you tell us which book this is from? Often TV distance is presented as a distance between distributions. I've never seen the form above. Also equal in distribution does not imply equal in a.s sense as your example clearly illustrates.

Comment: The book is 'Probability and random processes' by Grimmett, Stirzaker. Exercise 2.7.13 page 44, maybe it is an old copy which has been corrected since. Its good to know I'm not going mad!

Answer (score 0):

> Let $Ω$ be the sample space of tossing a fair coin once, let $X$ map heads to 
>   $0$, tails to $1$ and let $Y$ map heads to $1$ and tails to  $0$. Then it seems that the result does not hold.

Indeed, this is a counter example.  You have $\mathsf P(X=Y)=0$ but: $$\lvert\mathsf P(X=0)-\mathsf P(Y=0)\rvert + \lvert\mathsf P(X=1)-\mathsf P(Y=1)\rvert ~{= \lvert \tfrac 12-\tfrac 12\rvert+\lvert \tfrac 12-\tfrac 12\rvert\\=0}$$

---

If $\mathsf P(X=Y)=1$, then $X=Y$ almost surely and thus $\forall k : \mathsf P(X=k)=\mathsf P(Y=k)$ .

So $\mathsf P(X=Y)=1~\implies~d_{TV}(X,Y) = 0$.

However, as your counter example demonstrates, the converse is not so.